# Material Reflection Looks Like Mud

Tags: rendering, mirror

I have tried multiple tutorials online, and followed them exactly but each time I check off 'Mirror' in my material the render looks like this, instead of being shiny. After 5 hours of trying everything I could imagine I am stuck.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You don't check *Mirror* in textures, textures don't reflect on their own, materials do. What is there in your scene to reflect? Reflections only look as good as the environment they're reflecting, if your scene is empty there is nothing to appear reflected. Also check smoothing and make sure your normals aren't distorting reflections.

Comment: Ohhhh this is going to be the longest learning curve I have ever done :)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the need for more environment.

Comment: For a quick result in reflections use an [image for the world background](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/world/world_panel.html#textures)